# Is it possible to implement Python yield functionality in freestanding C?

Tags: python, c, asynchronous, yield

I recently came accross the `yield` keyword in Python (as well as JavaScript) - I understand that this is primarliy used for the generator pattern, but the language construct seems to be used in asynchronous functions as well where my interests lie. In asynchronous functions it may merely act as syntatic-sugar and I know there are alternative patterns to achieve the same effect - But I like it - A LOT!

I want to know if I can do something similar in C (even with inline assembly). I came across a Java implementation using threads https://github.com/mherrmann/java-generator-functions which I can more or less implement in C. However this is won't be a freestanding implementation, and my interest is purely in a freestanding implementation.

Coming to C co-routines (http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html), one of the deficits is that stack objects can't be used. However I am still OK with this since current asynchronous callback implementations also can't use the stack. However the problem lies in a freestanding implementation - I can't think of a way to collect all the register variables and store them without a hosted environment.

There's probably a solution using the `setjmp/longjmp`, however I am pretty sure these can't be implemented freestanding.

So the question is: Is it possible to implement Python yield functionality in **freestanding** C?

Personally I think I have exhausted the possibilites, so I'll ask this - If you could have a hosted implementation, how would you implement it (preferably with some macro magic)? I have a fairly ugly implementation which I'll post later on if nothing cool comes up.

Also I don't want C++ implementations - Unless you can wrap around the C++ with pure C functions.

EDIT: A basic requirement is that the generator function has to be re-enterant.

Comment: Given that the Python interpreter is written in C... yes?

Comment: I don't think so. You either need the standard library (which implements `setjmp` and `longjmp`), or you need to do some hardware specific operations, most likely involving assembly. Just how freestanding do you want it?

Comment: @mtijanic Hardware specific operations are fine. What I want is - If I could modify a C compiler and introduce a yield syntax then that syntax should be available in the first phase of compiling a compiler (when it can compile only freestanding code). It should not be dependent on any OS specific functions like when building the second phase of the compiler. Not sure if what I just said makes any sense to anyone.

Comment: @tinkerbeast: How do you feel about heap allocation?

Comment: Maybe implementation of [`setcontext`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setcontext) and similiar functions is worth looking? For example in glibc for x86_64: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/setcontext.S#102

Comment: This is kind of a cop out and not a proper answer but I got excited in much the same way when I first discovered co-routines in Lua, seeking to find ways to emulate the same effect in both C and C++, and I found something that I was okay with for a while until I found it to be bottlenecky and started implementing things the harder way as FSMs. IMO the language ought to be used the way it's meant to be. With C, we're looking at something pretty close to the hardware. If you embed something like a Lua interpreter on top, then you get a mix of the best from both worlds for different needs.

Comment: @Kevin All heap implementations are OS specific, so it throws out freestanding. Saying that, I have somewhat given upon a pure free-standing implementation. So if you can show me a clean way of doing things, I'm up for it.

Comment: @myaut `setcontext` was probably exactly what I was looking for. It's not freestanding, but it's definitely the most robust - It'll take care of the stack and everything.

Comment: @Ike I agee with whatever you said. Saying that however, I think freestanding C can do with a lot more extensions (Something like [D](http://dlang.org/), but maintaining compatibility with C). The real reason I want co-routines in C is because I think the current way of doing asynchrnous/call-back based programming is too clumsy.

Comment: @tinkerbeast Yeah, the idea of having something like `yield result` is immensely useful and can lead to much more readable/writable code. I guess it's a matter of how you want to look at C, as a general-purpose language to use solely to construct large-scale codebases, or one to really get closer to the hardware in those select areas where it pays off the most. I've tried the former approach and, over the years, found my niche by utilizing C more for the latter purpose in the most performance-critical areas, and using other languages for convenience and safety in the daily areas.

Comment: @tinkerbeast Somewhat opinion-based, but I found Lua to be wonderful for that purpose as something that's so easy to embed (the whole thing requires no special build process, is just a regular, ultra-portable ANSI C lib, and small enough to fit on a floppy). It just seems like it was designed to talk to C code making binding C functions to be callable from Lua a piece of cake, and with LuaJIT, you start to rival C performance there, but with concepts like coroutines and closures natively supported.

Comment: I have a C implementation that uses setjmp/longjmp but supports await and yield + next [here](https://bitbucket.org/akalsi87/ccio/src/work/tests/coro.cpp). The declarations are [here](https://bitbucket.org/akalsi87/ccio/src/work/include/ccio/coro.h)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to answer using `setjmp` and `longjmp` since those interfaces are standard and you can easily find their implementations for any HW platform. They are freestanding, but HW dependent.

```
struct _yield_state {
    jmp_buf buf;
    _Bool yielded;
};

#define yieldable  static struct _yield_state _state; \
                   if (_state.yielded) longjmp(_state.buf, 1); else {}


#define yield(x)  if (setjmp(_state.buf)) { _state.yielded = false;          }\
                  else                    { _state.yielded = true;  return x }

int func(int a, int b)
{
    yieldable;

    if (a > b)
        yield(0);

    return a + b;
}
```

---

You can find an example `setjmp` and `longjmp` implementation [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/arch/um/sys-x86_64/setjmp.S). It is pure assembly, specific only to the underlying hardware.

Comment: Since this solution uses static objects the function is non-rentrant. This will lead to a lot of problems. However I do think you're right about setjmp and longjmp being freestanding - Both LLVM and GCC seem to have builtins for these http://llvm.org/docs/ExceptionHandling.html#sjlj-intrinsics

Comment: @tinkerbeast True. You could modify it to take a state argument from the caller, possibly with something like `#define func(a, b) func(a, b, &state)`, but then the onus is on the caller to allocate the state. Another option is for the static object to be a list of states, and you pick one based on the argument passed by the caller. That argument could be a threadId, caller's `__FUNC__` or even a random number generated at compiletime.

Comment: don't you think this small piece of code has too many ways to break?

Answer (score 5):

Ignoring the language-specific jargon, what you're looking for is called "coroutines". Simon Tatham came up with something that looks and behaves very much like coroutines with some preprocessor magic. It doesn't *entirely* work the same way, but it pretends to in a way that is useful for most cases.

See [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html) for the full details.

Depending on your exact problem, this might be enough, or it might not be. The advantage of this method, at any rate, is that it works with standard C; no need for nonstandard compilers.

Answer (score 4):

Iterators in Python follow this pattern: You call them (with arguments) and they return an object.  You call that object's `.next()` or `.__next__()` method repeatedly and it runs through the iterator.

We can do something similar:

```
typedef struct iterator{
    int yield_position; /* Where to jump to */
    void *yield_state; /* opaque container for local variables */
    void *(*next)(iterator*); /* Function taking "this" argument 
                               returning a pointer to whatever we yielded */
} iterator;

iterator *make_generator(/* arguments? */){
    iterator *result = malloc(sizeof(iterator)); /* Caller frees */
    result->yield_position = 0;
    /* Optionally allocate/initialize yield_state here */
    result->next = do_generator;
    return result;
}

void *do_generator(iterator *this){
    struct whatever *result;
    switch(this->yield_position){
        case 0:
            /* Do something */
            this->yield_position = 1;
            /* Save local variables to this->yield_state if necessary */
            return (void *) result;
        case 1:
            /* Initialize local variables from this->yield_state */
            /* Etc.*/
    }
}

void free_generator(iterator *iter){
    /* Free iter->yield_state if necessary */
    free(iter);
}
```

Since case labels [can be used just about everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device), the switch should be able to e.g. jump into the middle of a loop if necessary.  You'll probably still need to re-initialize loop variables etc.

It's called like this:

```
iterator *iter = make_generator(/* arguments? */);
struct whatever *foo = iter->next(iter);
/* etc. */
free_generator(iter);
```

Passing the `this` argument by hand gets tedious, so define a macro:

```
#DEFINE NEXT(iter) ((iter)->next(iter))
```

Comment: if you free `iter` in the example you want to free `foo` as well. furthermore this doesn't cover multiple yield statements in a function right (the true power of coroutines)?

Comment: @Alex: You *might* want to free `foo`.  It's possible that you're interning your return values or doing some other clever thing like refcounting.  I've deliberately left it vague on that point to accommodate a wide variety of use cases.  And yes, you do get multiple yield statements.  Just add more case labels.  Note that every time you want to yield, you have to do the whole save-and-restore-locals dance.

Comment: What you *don't* get is `yield from`.  That one's still a bit complicated, especially if you want to add support for `.send()` etc.

Comment: yeah some cases are covered, but I think some things like recursion (not the ones that are reducible to tail calls) would be breaking this. don't get me wrong, the code that you posts shows nicely something good enough for many cases, for for a complete yield implementation you should be able to save the functions context and break out of it any time. if you want performance splitting it up as the programmer is probably going to be more effective.

Comment: @Alex: Recursion is trivial: Construct a new `iterator` struct for each level.